# Python - Is there a way to get who is calling (called from IDLE/Shell)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to get is the method called from IDLE/python shell?

For example:

```
def print_in_console():
    if called_from_python_shell:
        print('Called from console')
    ...do other stuff later
```

Comment: You could look for differences in `sys.argv`, but that could still be inconclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only feasible (easy) way I can see of doing this is by passing an argument / parameter to the function you're calling.

```py
def function (foo, bar, called_from):
    print (called_from)
    *** do stuff with foo and bar ***
```